# Catia Create project using XYZ component as direction inputs

Tags: vba, catia

i want to create HybridshapeProject from the given 2D points of a sketch

the project is creating like this refer below image
[image]

as you can see in the image the projects direction is created based on XYZ components of the selected vertex from the sketch

i have to get the components with VBA Code that i dont know

any help how to create HYbridshapeproject like this

the XYZ values in Direction Window those i need to get from selecting the axis system and the sketch which is present in the axis system

Answer (score 0):

In order to use components as direction in a projection, you have to set the property .normal to false and assign a value to the .direction property.
In the following example, I assume that the HybridShapeFactory (HSF) and the inputs for the projection (refProjectedElement, refProjectionSupport) has been declared:

```
Dim ProjectFeature As HybridShapeProject
Set ProjectFeature = HSF.AddNewProject(refProjectedElement, refProjectionSupport)
ProjectFeature.Normal = False
Dim ProjectionDirection As HybridShapeDirection
Set ProjectionDirection = HSF.AddNewDirectionByCoord(0#, 0.95, 0.05)
ProjectFeature.Direction = ProjectionDirection
```

The macro recorder should be able to deliver code for the projection along components.